# Spring 4 REST web-services not working with security

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring 4, with Spring Security 4 to secure web-services.  A normal web-service worked fine without security.   My secured web-services also seemed to work great working locally and with unit testing.

We are using the SiteMinder example, which means we have authentication happenind from a remote authority.  This delivers a token to the browser when we login.  We pass the authentication token with a request header, and this is pulled from customerUserDetailsService.  That class and methods pull the token from the header, authenticates the user against that remote authority, and we get a username.  From that username, we make a DAO call to our database to get the User Details and their Roles, which in the Spring Security Context uses the roles to grant authority.   This is all working fine, and we get an authenticated user and we have thier roles/grantedAuthorities.

So, as previously stated, we are now just securing web-services with spring-security.xml to secure the web-services based on the role of the user.  Again, this all seemed to work fine with unit testing.  We had a token for a user who did not have access to web-sites and we correctly got back a 403 error.  When we used a token for a user who did have the right role, was able to execute the web-service.

Now I am trying to deploy this into a new environment, and I am not having much luck.

So, I have a spring-security.xml that looks like:

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">

    <!-- Additional http configuration omitted -->

         <intercept-url pattern="/records/authorizedRecords" access="hasRole('portalUser')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/records/myCode" access="hasRole('portalUser')" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/users/email" access="hasRole('appAdmin')" />

    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="openAmFilter" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="openAmFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="principalRequestHeader" value="openam_token"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">

    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
        <beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"  class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
            <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>

</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider" />
</authentication-manager>   

<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.agmednet.server.security.CustomUserDetailsService"></beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="http403EntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint">
```

When we tried access to:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/users/email/*" access="hasRole('appAdmin')" />
```

this did not seem to match:

/rest/users/email/myemail@someemail.com

so I changed it to:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/rest/users/email/*" access="hasRole('appAdmin')" />
```

And I get this from the log.

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/rest/trials/integratedtrials'; against '/rest/users/email/*'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Public object - authentication not attempted
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /rest/trials/integratedTrials reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

At this point, I know we have an authenticated user, the username, and the roles are listed right there in the logs.  We seem to find a matching URL in the spring-security.xml, the URL matches, the roles match, and now I feel we should be executing the logic behind the web-service, but I get an error message:

> Apache Tomcat/8.0.30 - Error report
>   /services/rest/users/email/myemail@someemail.com
>
> The requested resource is not available.

I am absolutely floored here .... unsecured web-services work great. I have to be missing something? Is it with the word "rest" in the URL? Web-services have always worked when they were unsecured. I added security and add unit tests to test this all out, and now I am unsure of what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I am an idiot!!!!

In the /WEB-INF/web.xml file I had this defined:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I suppose that is why when I call any RESTful web-services with:

```
/rest/users/email/myemail@someemail.com
```

it doesn't work.

But when I use:

```
/api/users/email/myemail@someemail.com
```

now it works.

Conclusion:    I am an idiot!!!